# Linkedin html share tag ignore url and shares random content

Tags: html, button, linkedin-api, share

I'm having issues with the HTML share tag of LinkedIn.
Currently I'm using this tag with these values:

```
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;url=https://codemoocnet-8223f.web.app/users/profile?=e3a381b2-400e-403e-ace2-ffa26bdda92b&amp;title=profilo&amp;source=codemoocnet-8223f.web.app" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> "
```

But when you click on the button it gives a random preview and the link is truncated `e3a381b2-400e-403e-ace2-ffa26bdda92b` is taken off. WhatsApp Facebook and Twitter work well with og meta tags. Where's the problem?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the URL encoding of the link? Using `&` instead of `&amp;`?

Comment: yes, same result.. always same result, i think the problem is the "?=" before the id code that i use in the url but it would be stupid not to let users use certain combinations..

Comment: Do you have an example of what happens with the link?

Comment: try this.. it should give a page named like the title of the web and not "content_copy" which is a tag of an icon in materializecss.. i dont know where it gets lorem ipsum

https://imgur.com/xzUIDCm

Comment: That's weird, I just tried using the LinkedIn post inspector and it shows the correct information, check it out: https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/https:%2F%2Fcodemoocnet-8223f.web.app%2Fusers%2Fprofile%3F=e3a381b2-400e-403e-ace2-ffa26bdda92b&amp;title=profilo&amp;source=codemoocnet-8223f.web.app